# Have there been any anime that have been subjected to exclusive distribution rights?

Tags: anime-production

I see that this season, Kabaneri of the Iron Fortress is being streamed by Amazon, which holds exclusive distribution rights to the series and will also hold exclusive distribution rights to other series on the same network as Kabaneri in the future.

Even though I know that Amazon had acquired exclusive distribution rights to other non-anime series like Under the Dome, I was a bit surprised to see an anime title be subjected to exclusive distribution.

That led me to wonder: have there been any other anime that have been subjected to exclusive distribution rights in the past? In particular, by a party not dedicated to anime distribution like Amazon?

Comment: I heard some rumors about an anime being entirely produced by Netflix, maybe they'll only distribute it there?

Comment: How do you mean exclusive as with Under the Dome in Australia i can buy Season 3 from [JB Hifi](https://www.jbhifi.com.au/movies-tv-shows/movies-tv-shows-on-sale/tv-drama/under-the-dome-season-3/806351/) and it was aired on [Southern Cross Ten](http://tenplay.com.au/channel-ten/under-the-dome) which is free-to-air

Comment: Rights are almost always restricted to a single country, so even if Amazon has exclusive US distribution rights that won't affect what happens in AU. Similarly, it's not uncommon for one company to have exclusive distribution rights, but to also have the right to sublicense - so it's possible for, say, Funimation to have the US distribution rights for an anime, which then lets them make deals with Crunchyroll for online streaming, and some other company for producing DVDs and BluRays, and another company to play the show on TV.